# Should I use inject in BindAdapter class?

Tags: android, data-binding, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I have this method :

```
/**
 * Uses the Glide library to load an image by URL into an [ImageView]
 */
@BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
fun bindImage(imgView: ImageView, imgUrl: String?) {
    imgUrl?.let {
        val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
        Glide.with(imgView.context)
            .load(imgUri)
            .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_animation)
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image)
            )
            .into(imgView)
    }
}
```

inside a BindAdapter file.

Should I use the dagger to inject dagger inside this method?

If so, how do I do that because BindAdapter is a file, not a class?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this way

```
  @Singleton
  @Provides
  static RequestOptions provideRequestOptions(){
    return RequestOptions
            .placeholderOf(R.drawable.loading_animation)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_broken_image);
  }

  @Singleton
  @Provides
  static RequestManager provideGlideInstance(Application application, 
  RequestOptions requestOptions){
    return Glide.with(application)
            .setDefaultRequestOptions(requestOptions);
  }
```

In DataBinding Class

```
   @Inject
   RequestManager requestManager;

   @BindingAdapter("imageUrl")
  fun bindImage(imgView: ImageView, imgUrl: String?) {
  imgUrl?.let {
    val imgUri = imgUrl.toUri().buildUpon().scheme("https").build()
    requestManager
        .load(imgUri)
        .into(imgView)
   }
}
```

Comment: Do not place Android context classes in static fields (static reference to RequestManager which has field context pointing to Context); this is a memory leak more... this might work but i think this lint error is the answer

Comment: @JesusDimrix, Yes as you said lint is giving the warning, how did you bypass that warning? can you explain??